# How do I know the number of cards which have different colors from a set?

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:

> In an porcelain jar there is a set of $2016$ cards. These cards have a
> numbered printed on their faces and those are $1$ to $2016$, assume
> there is no repetition. These cards have a peculiar characteristic.
> The cards such that the sum of their numbers are the same are of the
> same color, and those that have these different sums are of a
> different color. Using this information find the number of different
> colored cards there are inside the jar.

The alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{26 cards}\\
2.&\textrm{27 cards}\\
3.&\textrm{28 cards}\\
4.&\textrm{29 cards}\\
5.&\textrm{25 cards}\\
\end{array}$

I'm a bit confused with this specific question. How exactly should I assess what is it intended?.

From reading at the problem, my interpretation is that there are two kinds of sets of cards.

*One group has cards whose numbers add up to the same amount as their partner. And these happen to be the same color*

*The other group is the opposite. They do not have a pair that adds up to the same number as the numbers that appear to be written on it. And these happen to have a different color*

Is this part correct?. If that's so. Then it comes into play the challenging part. **How to distinguish which from which set?**

What I attempted to diagnose first was the extreme situation:

This happens with $1999$

Since the maximum is $2016$ there will not be $9991$. In other words there is no reverse order. But that was the only card which I identified which must be a different color.

But how about the card below that number:

$1998$, it just happens that $1+9+9+8=27$

and this also occurs with $999$, as $9+9+9=27$. Hence, what to do here?. Does it exist a way to find which group and how many of these cards must have a different color?.

But again, is this the right way to approach this problem?.

Since I feel lost in this question. I'd like someone could help me with the **most detailed explanation as possible** and be include a **step by step** analysis of what should be done to solve this problem. Can someone help me?.

Comment: What exactly is the question? How many colors there are?

Comment: I have no idea what the assumptions on the cards means.

Comment: Wild Guess:  of those numbers, only $28$ is a divisor of $\frac {2016\times 2017}2$, so maybe that's the answer.

Comment: @John Hi. I'm sorry, I forgot to include this information as part of the question. The problem asked to find the number of different colored cards inside the jar.

Comment: @lulu I'm also confused. The problem, I think intends to state that there are two groups of cards, ones which has the sum of their digits the same, these come in pairs and they share the same colors. Others don't have the same sum hence are of different color. Or at least that's the way how I see it.

Comment: @lulu Sorry but the answer is not 28 according to my book. What could it be wrong?. It makes me confused. It is an interesting observation by the way.

Comment: What is the official answer?  Maybe we can reverse engineer the thing from that.  But....well, the issue here is that the problem is so poorly worded that all we can do is guess.

Comment: @lulu I'm deeply sorry for the delay. These days have been very exhausting for me. I checked with the answer in my book, which states to be $27$. I don't know why is it *off-by-one* maybe could be an error in the solution or maybe is it another interpretation?. By the way, **why** did you guessed that $28$ as being a divisor of 2016 woudl be the answer?. You mentioned that $28$ is a divisor of $\frac{2016\times 2017}{2}$ is this some property to find the divisor of a number i.e $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ or something?. How did you got to $28$ and **why** had it be the answer?. Is this some property?.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understood the problem statement is the way you sketched it; the cards would be coloured according to the sum of their digits. For example, the cards labeled 1, 10, 100 and 1000 would have the same colour and any cards with different sums would have to be coloured differently. For example, you would need a new colour for the cards numbered $2, 11, 101$ etc.

For the case $a = 1, b \in \{ 0,..., 9 \}, c \in \{0, ...,9 \}, d \in \{0, ..., 9\}$ you can get at most $a+b+c+d = 1+27 = 28$. No number abcd with  $2016 \geq abcd >2000$ or $abcd < 1000$ can get a higher sum so this means that you need **at most** $28$ colours to group your cards by the sum of their digits. On the other hand it seems that by choosing b, c , d in the above case with $a=1$ suitably you can sum to any number between 1 and 28, so that there would be in fact cards of $28$ different colours in the jar.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But If I understand you correctly. You are saying that by summing the numbers between $2016\geq abcd > 2000$ or the numbers in the range $abcd < 1000$ none of these can get to $28$?. Does this means if the maximum number is $28$ there will be **that** ammount of colors in the jar?. But I'm trying to find other number which can get to $28$ below $1999$ or higher than that and below $2016$ and I can't find it. Wouldn't this means that there would be more than one card which share the sum $27$ but there is **only one card** which its sum is $28$?.

Comment: Yes, summing the digits of numbers between 1-999 or 2000-2016 cannot get to 28, as can be checked by inspection. The original question -as I understood it- asks for the number of colours that are needed if cards are grouped into sets by the sum of their digits. Because the sum of digits can be at most 28, at most 28 colours are needed. Generally there will be many numbers with same colour, such as 1 10 and 100. 1999 seems to be the only card with sum of digits to 28.  But because you can find cards that sum to any number between 1-28 when they are numbered 1-2016 you do need all 28 colours.